# What is h(y) − h(y + 1) if h(y + 2) = y(y + 4)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am revising maths from the basic since last year. I came across a question that I resolved, but without confidence. I know something is wrong

I am also new to the Forum (3rd post), so not sure how to properly use the notations :)

**Could you please give me tips on:**

1. How to resolve it  Which method should be used (method's name?)
2. Where I can get more information about this (books, online...)
3. If this is part of pre-calculus or how can I understand it at its fullest?

---

**Here is my solution:**

Step 1. Solve for h(y + 2) = y(y + 4)

h(y+2) = y^2 +4y

*Then I offset and resolve:*

h(y) = (y-2)^2 + 4(y-2) `Not sure if I am allowed to do it this way`

h(y) = y^2 -4y + 4 + 4y -8

h(y) = y^2 - 4

*Step 2. Then replace for h(y) − f(y + 1)*

(y^2 - 4) - (y^2 - 4 +1) `This is where my biggest doubt is`

y^2 -4 - y^2 + 4 - 1

**Answer: -1**

I'm pretty sure something nasty is happening here...

Could you please help?

Cheers!

Comment: Typo fixed: Step 2. Then replace for h(y) − h(y + 1)

Comment: you substituted $h(y+1)$ with the value of $h(y) +1$. That is the error

Comment: By the way, the topic is not Linear Algebra, since you're dealing with quadratic expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made a mistake in the second last step while calculating $h (y+1) $. You forgot to **offset** the equation by $1$, which when done correctly would have given you: $$h (y)-h (y+1)$$ $$=(y^2-4)- (\color{red}{(y+1)^2}-4) $$ $$=-2y-1$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, I should have applied the same principle. Perhaps I just need more confidence and practice :)
Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$h(y+2)=y(y+4)$$ so $$h(y+1)=(y-1)(y+3)\quad \text{and}\quad h(y)=(y-2)(y+2)$$ Thus $$h(y)-h(y+1)=(y^2-4)-(y^2-2y-3)=2y-1$$

Comment: It is $\cdots y^2-\color{BLUE}{2y}-3\cdots$

Comment: Mistake! Compute $h (y+1) $ correctly..

Comment: @Holo  Thanks! edited :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thank you very much for introducing a new perspective to the problem. I can only accept one answer in the forum, apparently. So it will go to Rohan, since he based his answer on my approach. But I really appreciate your effort and time

Comment: @Trentini No problem :)